# REGEXP_REPLACE to replace list of values with list of values in single statement

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, replace

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('JUHETI BT MEMA', 'BT' ,'\BT',2) FROM dual;
```

This will replace escape character in front of the `BT`. But I have multiple list of words like `BT,SYS,PT` etc.. Now I want to replace all (BT,SYS,PT) with /BT,/SYS,/PT.

If word BY comes in middle means it should be replaced with /BT, if SYN comes means it should be replaced with /SYN.

How to acheive this in REGEXP?

I want to replace list of values (BT,SYN,PT) with list of values (/BT,/SYN,/PT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('JUHETI BT SYS PT MEMA', '((BT)|(SYS)|(PT))' ,'\\\1', 1) FROM dual;
```

> The replace_string can contain up to 500 backreferences to
>   subexpressions in the form \n, where n is a number from 1 to 9. If you
>   want to include a backslash () in replace_string, then you must
>   precede it with the escape character, which is also a backslash.

A subexpression is a fragment of pattern enclosed in parentheses. Subexpressions can be nested.
Subexpressions are numbered in order in which their left parentheses appear in
pattern. For example, consider the following expression:

```
0123(((abc)(de)f)ghi)45(678)
```

This expression has five subexpressions in the following order: `"abcdefghi"`
followed by `"abcdef"`, `"abc"`, `"de"` and `"678"`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to put a forward slash in front of select words?

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('JUHETI BT MEMA', 
                       '(BT|PT|SYN)',     --all words enclosed in brackets to from 1st capture group
                       '/\1'              --forward slash, followed by string matched by 1st capture group
                      )
FROM DUAL;
```